# Why am I getting "401 Unauthorized" response from Java Spotify-Api?

Tags: java, authentication, spotify

I am trying to learn Spotify API. I have already created an app from https://developer.spotify.com/ and get my ***Client ID*** and ***Client Secret***

Now what I am trying to do is get my profile's attributes. I have looked at the code samples from here https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-java and typed this code shown in below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String clientId = "My Client ID";
    final String clientSecret = "My Client Secret";
    Api api = Api.builder().clientId(clientId).clientSecret(clientSecret).build();
    
    
    /* Create a request object. */
    final ClientCredentialsGrantRequest request = api.clientCredentialsGrant().build();

    /* Use the request object to make the request, either asynchronously (getAsync) or synchronously (get) */
    final SettableFuture<ClientCredentials> responseFuture = request.getAsync();

    /* Add callbacks to handle success and failure */
    Futures.addCallback(responseFuture, new FutureCallback<ClientCredentials>() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(ClientCredentials clientCredentials) {
        /* The tokens were retrieved successfully! */
        System.out.println("Successfully retrieved an access token! " + clientCredentials.getAccessToken());
        System.out.println("The access token expires in " + clientCredentials.getExpiresIn() + " seconds");

        /* Set access token on the Api object so that it's used going forward */
        api.setAccessToken(clientCredentials.getAccessToken());
        /* Please note that this flow does not return a refresh token.
       * That's only for the Authorization code flow */
      }

      @Override
      public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
        /* An error occurred while getting the access token. This is probably caused by the client id or
         * client secret is invalid. */
          throwable.printStackTrace();
      }
    });

    final CurrentUserRequest currentUserRequest = api.getMe().build();

    try {
        final User user = currentUserRequest.get();

        System.out.println("Display name: " + user.getDisplayName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong! " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am retrieving access token succesfully but something going wrong when I try to get current user. Here is output of the code:

```
Successfully retrieved an access token! [my access token]
The access token expires in 3600 seconds
Something went wrong! 401
com.wrapper.spotify.exceptions.BadRequestException: 401
    at com.wrapper.spotify.SpotifyHttpManager.handleErrorStatusCode(SpotifyHttpManager.java:178)
    at com.wrapper.spotify.SpotifyHttpManager.execute(SpotifyHttpManager.java:157)
    at com.wrapper.spotify.SpotifyHttpManager.get(SpotifyHttpManager.java:53)
    at com.wrapper.spotify.methods.AbstractRequest.getJson(AbstractRequest.java:34)
    at com.wrapper.spotify.methods.CurrentUserRequest.get(CurrentUserRequest.java:32)
    at com.kadir.spotify.Main.main(Main.java:52)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Your are going "too fast". Your future hasn't completed by the time you call ` User user = currentUserRequest.get();`

Comment: Maybe starting with https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-java/blob/master/examples/GetAuthenticatedUserInformation.java is simpler

Comment: @reto What is `code` in line 25? I only have client id and client secret

Comment: Please carefully ready the linked documentation: https://developer.spotify.com/spotify-web-api/authorization-guide/#authorization_code_flow